# String Concatenation Function in Dataclass not working as expected

Tags: string, kotlin, concatenation, isnullorempty

I'm sure a simple reason for this, but I can't see why the function `projectTitleText()` in below dataclass isn't concatenating as expected in my recyclerView:

```js
data class ProjectObject (
    var projectReference: String = "NO REFERENCE",
    var projectTitle: String = "", // e.g. "C & F Beam Reconfiguration"
    var projectDescription: String = "", // e.g. "Order for beam reconfiguration project"
    var projectStatus: String = "Enquiry",
    var projectNotes: String = "",
    var projectTask: Boolean = false,

    var createdBy: String = "",
    var users: HashMap<String, Boolean> = hashMapOf(),
    var sites: HashMap<String, Boolean> = hashMapOf(),
    var contacts: HashMap<String, Boolean> = hashMapOf(),

    @ServerTimestamp
    var dateCreatedTimestamp: Date? = null,
    @ServerTimestamp
    var dateEditedTimestamp: Date? = null,

    @Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude
    var projectID: String = ""

) : Serializable {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return projectReference
    }

    fun projectTitleText(): String {
        var projectTitleText = projectReference
        if (projectTitle.isNotEmpty()) projectTitleText.plus(" - $projectTitle")
        return projectTitleText
    }

}
```

I know that there is a value in `projectTitle` so either `.isNotEmpty()` or `.plus()` functions are not working as I expected..

In my adapter, the code looks like this:

```js
    class ProjectViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(
            project: ProjectObject,
            clickListener: (ProjectObject) -> Unit,
            longClickListener: (ProjectObject) -> Boolean
        ) {
            // Set text fields
            itemView.projectsItemTitleText.text = project.projectTitle
            itemView.projectsItemDetailsText.text = project.projectDescription
            itemView.projectsItemContactsText.text = project.projectContactsText() // Not working!!
            itemView.projectsStatusButton.text = project.projectStatus

            // Set Task Icon visibility
            if (project.projectTask) itemView.projectsItemTaskImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else itemView.projectsItemTaskImageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            //Set Status background colour
            when (project.projectStatus) {
                "Enquiry" -> itemView.projectsStatusButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.Enquiry))
                "Quote" -> itemView.projectsStatusButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.Quote))
                "Order" -> itemView.projectsStatusButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.Order))
                "Dead" -> itemView.projectsStatusButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.Dead))
                "Lost" -> itemView.projectsStatusButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.Lost))
            }

            // Set Listeners
            itemView.setOnClickListener { clickListener(project) }
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener { longClickListener(project) }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `projectTitle` when you execute this code?

Comment: So when it pulls data from Firestore, it is whatever is in the database (e.g. '22225' for Reference 'New Warehouse' for Title).  So projectTitleText should show  '22225 - New Warehouse'..  I'll add the code where this is used in the adapter for clarity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's (and hence Kotlin's) Strings are immutable. According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/plus.html), `plus`

> Returns a string obtained by concatenating this string with the string representation of the given other object.

meaning that `plus` will not modify the original String (it can't), it will produce a new one. Your code, therefore, has to be changed to the following to work properly:

```
fun projectTitleText(): String {
  var projectTitleText = projectReference
  if (projectTitle.isNotEmpty()) projectTitleText = projectTitleText.plus(" - $projectTitle")
  return projectTitleText
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the full response Egor - I knew it was simple, just couldn't see the issue.